# TCP Server Accepts packet for one time

Tags: java, android, eclipse, tcpserver

Please help,
    When i send tcp packet it's accepted just for 
    the first time but after...the tcp packet sender
    i use tells me that the packet is sent 
    but the program no response

```html
public void run() {
    try
    {
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(message.getPort());
            //ss.setSoTimeout(10000);
            System.out.println("before loop");
            while (true) {
                Looper.prepare();
                System.out.print("in");
                Socket s = ss.accept();
                System.out.print("out");
                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
                int i;
                String Msg = "";
                while((i=in.read())!=-1)
                {
                    System.out.println((char)i);
                    Msg += (char)i;
                }
                System.out.println(Msg);
                for (GotResponseListener listener : listeners)                      
                {
                    // Looper.prepare();
                    listener.onGotResponse(Msg);
                    System.out.println("Raised");
                    // Looper.loop();
                }
                Looper.loop();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
            //if timeout occurs
            // e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ss != null) {
                try {
                    ss.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        message.setText("r");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't send TCP packets, you send data. Your question is unclear.

Comment: I am new in android programming i made a sender but i can't make a server i want to know how to make it

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with Android per se, this is Java networking. I suggest you go read some books/tutorials about networking in Java.